# How to compile C/C++ programs to a exe format

Tags: c++, c, windows, macos, compilation

I'm using a mac OS X 10.8.4 64 bit.
I want to build some C/C++ programs on my mac, and then show them to some people who use windows.
I can successfully compile it into an exe, using

`g++ test.cpp -o test.exe` on the terminal

But when run in my PC, that exe file raises this error: "This verison of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) verion of the program."
Note: My PC is also 64 bits

Comment: If you're running that command on OS X, all you did is give the file name a ".exe" ending. You need to actually compile it for windows, which would require you to set up cross-compiling on OS X or set up a compiler on Windows.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to install Windows on a VM (use VirtualBox, or, VMware Fusion, or ...) and grab a copy of [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe` does not produce a Windows EXE executable, it just produces a Mac OS X executable that happens to have the `.exe` extension on its filename. To produce Windows EXE executables you need to use a Windows compiler, such as Microsoft Visual Studio or gcc on cygwin.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but does that mean that there is no way of creating a C/C++ executable windows file from a mac?

Comment: Yes, there is. You will nave to _cross compile_ using, for instance, MinGW.

Comment: No, it's possible, but it is WAY more involved than you probably want to get into. It requires cross-compiling (compiling something with a separate build and target environment). This is relatively common for trickier targets like embedded platforms, but between Mac OS X and Windows it's either never or almost never done. At least I've never heard of anyone doing it.

Comment: Cross-compiling for desktop isn't heard of. It doesn't actually get you out of having to *have* e.g. a Windows machine (since you need to test), but it allows you to have just one build machine.